# Phaser: How to call a function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, platformer, phaser

So I actually have the following code that works:﻿

```js
var player;
var box_tnt;

function create (){
    this.physics.add.collider(player, box_tnt, hitTnt, null, this);
}

//the function hitTnt stop the game because the player died
function hitTnt (player, boxes){
   this.physics.pause();
   console.log('Game Over!');
   textGameOver.setText('GAME OVER');
   player.setTint(0xff0000);
   player.anims.play('default');
   gameOver = true;﻿﻿﻿
}
```

and I want to do something like:

```js
var player;
var box_tnt;

function create (){
    this.physics.add.collider(player, box_tnt, hitTnt, null, this);
}

//the function hitTnt stop the game because the player died
function hitTnt (player, boxes){
    gameOver();
    //other stuff here
}

function gameOver (){
    this.physics.pause();
    console.log('Game Over!');
    textGameOver.setText('GAME OVER');
    player.setTint(0xff0000);
    player.anims.play('default');
    gameOver = true;﻿﻿﻿
}
```

but I have the following error message:

> TypeError: gameOver is not a function

Do you have please any ideas how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

`gameOver = true;﻿﻿﻿`
this overwrites `gameOver`; it used to be a function, now it's a boolean holding `true` value.

Comment: Thank you for making me realise this stupid mistake, know I can access the function that I renamed `gameEnd();` but I still have the following error:  `this.physics is undefined` How do I please pass `this.` and `player.` from `function hitTnt` to `function gameEnd` ?